# TimescaleDB wildcard (%) slow

Tags: postgresql-12, timescaledb

I have a timescaledb hypertable like this:

```
create table logs
(
    time         timestamp not null,
    partitionkey text      not null,
    ip           inet,
    raw          text,
    transformed  double precision
);
```

And indexes as follows:

```
create index logs_time_idx
    on logs (time desc);

create unique index logs_partitionkey_time_uindex
    on logs (partitionkey asc, time desc);
```

When I run this query, it takes 20 minutes to complete:

```
SELECT * FROM data.logs 
WHERE partitionkey LIKE '%m.60.05482730' 
AND time > NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days'
```

But when I run this one, it takes 2 seconds:

```
SELECT * FROM data.logs 
WHERE partitionkey LIKE '865617033605366.m.60.05482730'
AND time > NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days'
```

I tried indexing only the partitionkeys to help the wildcard query find matching values, but that had no effect.

```
-- created this index later to try and fix the slow wildcard query
create index logs_partitionkey_index
    on logs (partitionkey);
```

Explain plan for wildcard query:

```
Gather  (cost=1000.57..525711.89 rows=1219 width=81)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Parallel Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on logs  (cost=0.57..524589.99 rows=509 width=82)
        Chunks excluded during startup: 2
        ->  Parallel Index Scan using _hyper_2_10_chunk_logs_time_idx on _hyper_2_10_chunk  (cost=0.57..263956.91 rows=255 width=81)
              Index Cond: ("time" > (now() - '3 days'::interval))
              Filter: (partitionkey ~~ '%m.60.05482730'::text)
        ->  Parallel Index Scan using _hyper_2_9_chunk_logs_time_idx on _hyper_2_9_chunk  (cost=0.57..260629.72 rows=252 width=83)
              Index Cond: ("time" > (now() - '3 days'::interval))
              Filter: (partitionkey ~~ '%m.60.05482730'::text)
JIT:
  Functions: 8
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
```

Explain for specific partionkey value:

```
Custom Scan (ChunkAppend) on logs  (cost=0.44..903.08 rows=790 width=82)
  Chunks excluded during startup: 2
  ->  Index Scan using _hyper_2_9_chunk_logs_partitionkey_time_uindex on _hyper_2_9_chunk  (cost=0.57..447.44 rows=392 width=83)
        Index Cond: ((partitionkey = '865617033605366.m.60.05482730'::text) AND ("time" > (now() - '3 days'::interval)))
        Filter: (partitionkey ~~ '865617033605366.m.60.05482730'::text)
  ->  Index Scan using _hyper_2_10_chunk_logs_partitionkey_time_uindex on _hyper_2_10_chunk  (cost=0.57..452.27 rows=396 width=81)
        Index Cond: ((partitionkey = '865617033605366.m.60.05482730'::text) AND ("time" > (now() - '3 days'::interval)))
        Filter: (partitionkey ~~ '865617033605366.m.60.05482730'::text)
```

Is TimescaleDB not able to do wildcard (%) queries, or do I miss an index?

Comment: Since you complain about TimescaleDB dealing with wildcard query, have you observed that PostgreSQL without hypertable was able to deliver much better performance?

Comment: I personally expect that wildcard at the beginning of a string requires to scan all records within the relevant chunks and cannot utilize the index on the string column.This is demonstrated in the explain plans.

Comment: @k_rus I come from Influxdb to Timescaledb, so I do not know the inner workings of Postgresql.

Comment: Where do you see that the wildcard query scans all records in the chunks? I see "Parallel Index Scan using _hyper_2_10_chunk_" and I interpret this as the index is scanned, not all records. Is there something specific I need to see in the explain plan?

Comment: It uses index on time, so it scans all records, which satisfy the condition on time, and doesn't utilise string values to reduce amount of data to read.

Comment: I suggest to improve your question and focus what the actual problem you want to solve instead of focusing what you don't like. My understanding you want to know if you can get better performance and how, which is already answered below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A B-Tree index can't be used for a LIKE condition with a right-anchored wildcard. `'%...'` it can only be used for a left-anchored wildcard `'...%'`. You would need a trigram index to improved that.

If the length of your substring search is always the same, you could create an index on that expression. Including the time column in that index would probably help as well

```
create index logs_partitionkey_index
    on logs ( (right(partitionkey,13), "time" );
```

And change your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data.logs 
WHERE right(partitionkey,13) = 'm.60.05482730' 
  AND "time" > NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days'
```

---

Alternatively, create an index on the reversed string:

```
create index logs_partitionkey_index
    on logs ( (reverse(partitionkey) varchar_pattern_ops);
```

Then change your query to:

```
SELECT * 
FROM data.logs 
WHERE reverse(partitionkey) like reverse('m.60.05482730')||'%'
  AND "time" > NOW() - INTERVAL '3 days'
```

Comment: Thanks for your first suggestion regarding the fixed offset string. That tells me that I should split up the partition key before inserting into the table, and insert the first part into a dedicated column. So partionkey becomes 'm.60.05482730'.

Comment: @JPM: that indeed sounds like the better solution.